# Is the canonical map $T : L^1(\Omega, \mu, \mathbb R) \to (L^\infty(\Omega, \mu, \mathbb R))^*$ injective?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, banach-spaces, lp-spaces, dual-spaces

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal F, \mu)$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure space. We define a map
$$
T : L^1(\Omega, \mu, \mathbb R) \to (L^\infty(\Omega, \mu, \mathbb R))^*
$$
by
$$
(T u) (f) := \int_{\Omega} uf \ \mathrm d \mu
\quad \forall u \in L^1(\Omega, \mu, \mathbb R), \forall f \in L^\infty(\Omega, \mu, \mathbb R).
$$

> Is $T$ injective?

**My attempt** Let $u \in L^1(\Omega, \mu, \mathbb R)$ such that
$$
\int_{\Omega} uf \ \mathrm d \mu = 0 \quad \forall f \in L^\infty(\Omega, \mu, \mathbb R).
$$

Let $\Omega_n := \{|u| \le n\}$ and $f_n := u 1_{\Omega_n}$. Then $f_n \in L^\infty(\Omega, \mu, \mathbb R)$ and $f_n \to u$ pointwise everywhere. Then
$$
\int_{\Omega} uf_n \ \mathrm d \mu = 0 \quad \forall n.
$$

It's unfortunate that we can not apply DCT.

Comment: Your map seems to be the canonical embedding $L^1 \to (L^1)^{**}$, is it?

Comment: @ArcticChar You're right! Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @ArcticChar remarked in a comment, $T$ is the canonical injection from $L^1(\Omega, \mu, \mathbb R)$ to its bidual, so it is in fact an isometric isomorphism. This claim can be found at page *8* of Brezis's *Functional Analysis*.

Comment: To be precise, the canonical map $X\to X^{**}$ is only injective, so it's an isometric isomorphism **onto its image**.